# SwiftUI: Cannot open window.open() javascript call on page in wkwebview with ui delegate createWebViewWithConfiguration

Tags: swift, swiftui, webview, uikit, wkwebview

I have gone through a lot of different StackOverflow threads & Apple Developer pages to figure out what is going on here. I believe I am so close.

I have a WebView that runs on a site for a bit. Eventually the user can click a link that would open a new tab. It is opened via a window.open() call in JavaScript in the HTML.

However, on SwiftUI nothing runs, and I have set-up what should be the proper UIDelegate. This function never gets entered as I step through the call to WebView.

My question is: How can I make sure the UIDelegate is properly set? Where does this occur? Do I have the right spot?

My implementation (shortened):

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        // Enable javascript in WKWebView to interact with the web app
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        // Here "iOSNative" is our interface name that we pushed to the website that is being loaded
//        configuration.userContentController.add(self.makeCoordinator(), name: "iOSNative")
        configuration.preferences = preferences
        
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
        
//        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
//        webView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        
//        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
//        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
       return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.load(request)
    }

class Coordinator : NSObject, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView
        var webViewNavigationSubscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil
        
        init(_ uiWebView: WebView) {
//            uiWebView.uiDelegate = self
            self.parent = uiWebView
        }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            // Suppose you don't want your user to go a restricted site
if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
                if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                    return
                }
            }
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration!, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction!, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures!) -> WKWebView! {
//            if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
//                UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!)
//            }
//            return nil
            if (!(navigationAction.targetFrame?.isMainFrame ?? false)) {
              webView.load(navigationAction.request)
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        func webView(webView: WKWebView!, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration!, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction!, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures!) -> WKWebView! {
            if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
                UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!)
            }
            return nil
        }
}
}
```

My thoughts:

- Am I assigning uiDelegate & navigationDelegate in the right spots? It doesn't seem that my `createWebViewWith` delegate ever gets called. The app opens HTML links in  tags with target = "_blank", it's just this one that is called via window.open(x) in javascript.

My resources:
[WKWebView and window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190234/wkwebview-and-window-open)
[Window.open() is not working in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559666/window-open-is-not-working-in-wkwebview)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664267
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68427